Does OpenDNP3 support 64-bit types (uint64, int64)?
So, I'm working on my first project with OpenDNP3, and creating a converter between this protocol and a different one.  So far so good, except I'm trying to handle an incoming I64 value from the other protocol, and I don't actually see a way to handle it in OpenDNP3.  For example the ICommandHandler
https://dnp3.github.io/docs/cpp/3.1.0/d7/d3e/classopendnp3_1_1_i_command_handler.html
Supports I16, I32, Float, and Double, but appears to be it. In fact I did a search through their source code and doc and can't find definitive evidence of 64-bit data processing/
Is this true?  Is there any support for I64 and U64 types in OpenDNP3?
Thanks for any insight.

The web page for this library says that it is discontinued since 2022 btw.

According to https://www.dnp.org/Portals/0/AboutUs/DNP3%20Primer%20Rev%20A.pdf the DNP3 protocol itself only supports:

analog data can be represented by variation numbers as follows:

A 32-bit integer value with flag
A 16-bit integer value with flag
A 32-bit integer value
A 16-bit integer value
A 32-bit floating point value with flag
A 64-bit floating point value with flag


So I'd guess that Opendp3 is simply following the protocol.
Note that double can accurately store up to a 53 bit integer which may be enough for your use case.
